# Airflow SSHExecuteOperator() with env=... not setting remote environment

Tags: python, ssh, airflow

I am modifying the environment of the calling process and appending to it's PATH along with setting some new environment variables. However, when I print os.environ in the child process, these changes are not reflected. Any idea what may be happening?

My call to the script on the instance:

```
ssh_hook = SSHHook(conn_id=ssh_conn_id)
temp_env = os.environ.copy()
temp_env["PATH"] = "/somepath:"+temp_env["PATH"]
run = SSHExecuteOperator(
        bash_command="python main.py",
        env=temp_env,
        ssh_hook=ssh_hook,
        task_id="run",
        dag=dag)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Particularly if you've got `ssh` in play (as implied by tagging but *not* title or text), there are a lot of variables at hand.

Comment: I am just ssh-ing into a Compute Engine instance and running a script there. I am doing so using a service account via airflow using the SSHExecuteOperator. Providing code would mean exposing credentials.

Comment: Part of a [mcve] is that it's something that folks trying to test their own answer can run themselves on their own machines (otherwise it's not "verifiable") -- so you wouldn't want to include environment-specific credentials (or environment-specific code) anyhow.

Comment: btw, as something that depends on less magic in airflow, consider `bash_command="env foo=bar python main.py"` to run `python main.py` with `foo` exported in the environment with the value `bar`. If the change isn't reflected even with *that* done, that provides compelling evidence that your change is being replaced/overwritten/backed out *after* the process starts.

Comment: Makes sense. I want to prevent putting it in the command though, since the commands are logged and the keys need to remain secure. Another funny thing that happens is performing os.system("cat xyx.txt") works when run within my script on gce, but with open("xyz.txt") as blah... results in an IOError. What exactly is going on with the environment?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in purely local code, with airflow/ssh/etc. removed? If you can, that might provide an improved path towards making it an answerable question. Otherwise, I'm going to need to look into details of how airflow works -- and if it's using SSH facilities to pass environment variables out-of-band from the command, we might need to look at SSH server configuration etc (the server *can* be configured to disallow client-provided environment variables via the official channel for the purpose).

Comment: Everything works seamlessly locally. The problem arises only with airflow :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation: Implementation Analysis

If you look at the source to Airflow's [`SSHHook` class](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/ssh_hook.html), you'll see that it doesn't incorporate the `env` argument into the command being remotely run *at all*. The [`SSHExecuteOperator` implementation](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/ssh_execute_operator.html) passes `env=` through to the `Popen()` call on the hook, but that only passes it through to the local `subprocess.Popen()` implementation, **not** to the remote operation.

Thus, in short: Airflow does not support passing environment variables over SSH. If it were to have such support, it would need to either incorporate them into the command being remotely executed, or to add the `SendEnv` option to the ssh command being locally executed for each command to be sent (which even then would only work if the remote sshd were configured with `AcceptEnv` whitelisting the specific environment variable names to be received).

---

#### Workaround: Passing Environment Variables On The Command Line

```
from pipes import quote # in Python 3, make this "from shlex import quote"

def with_prefix_from_env(env_dict, command=None):
    result = 'set -a; '
    for (k,v) in env_dict.items():
        result += '%s=%s; ' % (quote(k), quote(v))
    if command:
        result += command
    return result

SSHExecuteOperator(bash_command=prefix_from_env(temp_env, "python main.py"),
                   ssh_hook=ssh_hook, task_id="run", dag=dag)
```

---

#### Workaround: Remote Sourcing

If your environment variables are sensitive and you don't want them to be logged with the command, you can transfer them out-of-band and source the remote file containing them.

```
from pipes import quote

def with_env_from_remote_file(filename, command):
  return "set -a; . %s; %s" % (quote(filename), command)

SSHExecuteOperator(bash_command=with_env_from_remote_file(envfile, "python main.py"),
                   ssh_hook=ssh_hook, task_id="run", dag=dag)
```

Note that `set -a` directs the shell to export all defined variables, so the file being executed need only define variables with `key=val` declarations; they'll be automatically exported. If generating this file from your Python script, be sure to quote both keys and values with `pipes.quote()` to ensure that it only performs assignments and does not run other commands. The `.` keyword is a POSIX-compliant equivalent to the bash `source` command.

Comment: But if you look at the Popen method of SSHHook, it takes the env etc as **kwargs and passes it on to another call to Popen as such :

prefixed_cmd = self._prepare_command(cmd)
 return subprocess.Popen(prefixed_cmd, **kwargs)

Comment: Yes, but that's passed to the **local** execution of the `ssh` command. Nothing is ever done that tells `ssh` to send it to the remote system -- you'd need to combine `SendEnv` and `AcceptEnv` as described in this answer to have that effect.

Comment: You can test this yourself with no Python involved: `foo="bar" ssh localhost 'echo "$foo"'` won't see the value of `bar`. It's completely bog-standard semantics of OpenSSH.

Comment: Riiiiight. So I tried setting the key in a file on the server and using os.system to source that file. It STILL does not set the environment variable I need!

Comment: `os.system()` launches a new shell, which exits as soon as the call returns. The problem should be obvious: The variable might be transiently set in that new shell, but once your `system()` call has returned, that shell is no longer running.

Comment: Use `bash_command="set -a; source somefile; exec python main.py"` if you want to source a remote file to set environment variables.

Comment: So is there a way I can read that key from a file?  I don't know why the file is visible to os.system but not to python open()

Comment: I frankly disbelieve that claim, and would need to see a [mcve] reproducing it in order to respond. Probably there's an `os.chdir()` or some other unexpected operation going on between point A and point B. Anyhow, I *did* give you a workaround.

Comment: I will reproduce the error and show you what I mean. will just change around the variables.

Comment: Thank you though, I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am grateful for the insights shared by Charles. The following workaround builds upon his solution, enhancing it to accommodate both script strings and script file paths within the `command` parameter.

```
class SSHEnvOperator(SSHOperator):
    def execute(self, context=None):
        # Append set env to command
        if self.environment:
            env_prefix = ''
            for (k,v) in self.environment.items():
                env_prefix +=  f'export {k}="{v}";\n'
            self.command = env_prefix + self.command
        super().execute(context=context)

# this works
SSHEnvOperator(bash_command="python main.py"), ssh_hook=ssh_hook, task_id="run", dag=dag) 
# this also works
SSHEnvOperator(bash_command="path/to/script.sh"), ssh_hook=ssh_hook, task_id="run", dag=dag)
```